# handle objects array for UITableView methods

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've researched the site and other sources online, but couldn't find a direct addressing to what I am asking. I have the following code in my class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

     KJCustomAdTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomerAdCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [_adsObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //    AdObject *someAd = _adsObjectArray[0];
    //    cell.titlePl  aceholderLabel.text = someAd.title;
    //    cell.locationPlaceholderLabel.text = someAd.location;
    return cell;
}
```

When I tried this with an array of strings, it worked well and I could get a table with all items in the array. But when I tried with my array of AdObjects, it didn't work. I tried a for loop to go through the array, but learned that this method is called for creation of each cell row, hence caused my whole table to reflect the same title for all rows.

I seek your help or a tutorial/question in another location that would address this problem...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `_adsObjectArray[0]` instead of `_adsObjectArray[indexPath.row]`?

Comment: Explain how is _adsObjectArray is created. And what your want.
The relevant code (pure guess from what I read from your code): `AdObject *someAd = [_adsObjectArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; cellTitlePlaceholderLabel.text = someAd.title;`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and with your question you answered mine! Thanks mate

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if you want to create an answer and post it, I will select it. Your hint solved my problem

Comment: Just a comment on style.  Move the registerNib into your viewDidLoad and you should only need to,call dequeue one time.  In this case you're using different reuseIdentifiers as well.  Seems like your code hasn't been fully transitioned yet.

Comment: @spacemonkey Don't worry about it - you've got two perfectly good answers to choose from. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight respect!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a title from your array you need to do this:

```
AdObject *someAd = _adsObjectArray[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = someAd.title;
```

instead of:

```
AdObject *someAd = _adsObjectArray[0];
cell.textLabel.text = someAd.title;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use object for current cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

     KJCustomAdTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomerAdCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
    }

    AdObject *someAd = [_adsObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titlePlaceholderLabel.text = someAd.title;
    cell.locationPlaceholderLabel.text = someAd.location;
    return cell;
}
```

Also you are using "cell reusing" in wrong way and at least you should use same identifier for same cell type.

Comment: Thanks will fix that :)